# Ionic deeplink shows blank page before the deeplink/page is pushed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, deep-linking

I am using ionic deeplinks. I have a service where I initialize the deeplink function like:

```
 initDeepLink(nav: Nav) {
  this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(nav, {
        '/page1/ PageComponent1,
    })
 }...
```

I call this function in my main app.component.ts , inside `onAllReady()` function, from the service with:

```
this.calldeepLinkServ.initDeepLink(this.nav);
```

where this.nav is of type:

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
```

declared in app.component.ts

When I visit a deeplink on my device, it works fine and goes to the given page (PageComponent1), but there is always a blank page before it and then the transition sort of jumps and push the deeplink page.

It never push (slide from right) the new page in the top of the current one opened in my app. I was trying to put the `@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav` inside the deeplink service rather the `app.component.ts`, but it acts the same.

I also tried to see if there is a method to disable the native page push in `this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController()` but it does not have any properties like that (like animate: false for example which is available for `NavController`).

So I am really not sure how to prevent this bad navigation experience with deeplinks i am sure that this is not a typical transition for ionic deeplinks, it looks bad for UI.

Answer (score 0):

So I've sorted this one out, instead:

```
this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController
```

I am using:

```
 this.deeplinks.route
```

and than i check what is passed on inside the match.$link. So depending on the query send through like

```
if (match.$link['path'].indexOf('/page1/') !== -1) {...}
```

I call the nav push, with animate:false and it does not uses the default nav push animation.